# How to exclude some raw pdfs in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have a collection over a thousand raw pdfs.  How can I exclude some raw pdfs are not needed.  I have a code but not know how to exclude e001.pdf and e002.pdf.  Thanks in advance.

collection: /electric-pdf

I try to exclude two pdfs (e001.pdf, e002.pdf) in collection

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $pdf-uris := cts:uris(
             (),(),
                     cts:and-query((
                       cts:collection-query("/electric-pdf"),
                       cts:not-query(what's cts function should I use exclude e001.pdf, e002.pdf in collection )
                     ))  

             )
return $pdf-uris
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`cts:document-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:document-query), which accepts a sequence of URIs. For example:

```
cts:not-query(cts:document-query(('1e001.pdf', e002.pdf'))
```

Comment: Note that `cts:document-query` expects full database uris, so you'd have to include the directory, if any..